# Grep multiple inputs from huge file, but only the first occurance each

Tags: awk, grep, filtering, unique

I am trying to build a "unique" zipcode list based on the data from geojson.
The goal is to grep one whole line per zip code. There are multiple entries per zipcode possible, all i care is about grabbing one per Zip.

ive prepared a "unique" zip code file to pass as grep to run as a "filter" against the list.
However, this still returns multiple results per zip code.
When limiting the results with -m 1 then i only get the very first match.

How can i filter one entry per line from the "big file"?

The input (example)

```
9417 TG
9423 TA
9431 HK
9883 TB
9965 TN
```

The command:
`grep -f infile.txt bigfile.txt`

the output:

```
9417 TG Spier   Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.8178 6.4592  ;
9423 TA Hoogersmilde    Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.9098 6.3685  ;
9417 TG Spier   Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.8178 6.4658  ;
9423 TA Hoogersmilde    Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.9066 6.3802  ;
9431 HK Westerbork  Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.8613 6.6029  ;
9431 HK Oosterwolde Friesland                                   NLD Netherlands 52.9851 6.2986  ;
9883 TB Zuurdijk    Groningen                                   NLD Netherlands 53.3147 6.3558  ;
9965 TN Zuurdijk    Groningen                                   NLD Netherlands 53.3506 6.3691  ;
9965 TN Leens   Groningen                                   NLD Netherlands 53.3523 6.37    ;
9883 TB Oldehove    Groningen                                   NLD Netherlands 53.3108 6.3632  ;
```

As you can see, there are two entries for `9423 TA` and `9965 TN`

How can I crunch that down to one entry per list?

Thank you kindly for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the job that is more suitable for `awk`:

```bash
awk '
NR == FNR {
   zip[$1] = $2
   next
}
$2 == zip[$1] {
   print
   delete zip[$1]
}' infile.txt bigfile.txt

9417 TG Spier   Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.8178 6.4592  ;
9423 TA Hoogersmilde    Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.9098 6.3685  ;
9431 HK Westerbork  Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.8613 6.6029  ;
9883 TB Zuurdijk    Groningen                                   NLD Netherlands 53.3147 6.3558  ;
9965 TN Zuurdijk    Groningen                                   NLD Netherlands 53.3506 6.3691  ;
```

Comment: I have no idea of what the syntax does, but hey! It works out exactly as I needed, Thank you!

Comment: It is fairly simple syntax if you understand awk programming. I would suggest [Effective Awk Programming](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

You might use GNU `AWK` to deduplicate records at 1st field in `bigfile.txt` as follows, let `bigfile.txt` content be

```
9417 TG Spier   Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.8178 6.4592  ;
9423 TA Hoogersmilde    Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.9098 6.3685  ;
9417 TG Spier   Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.8178 6.4658  ;
9423 TA Hoogersmilde    Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.9066 6.3802  ;
9431 HK Westerbork  Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.8613 6.6029  ;
9431 HK Oosterwolde Friesland                                   NLD Netherlands 52.9851 6.2986  ;
9883 TB Zuurdijk    Groningen                                   NLD Netherlands 53.3147 6.3558  ;
9965 TN Zuurdijk    Groningen                                   NLD Netherlands 53.3506 6.3691  ;
9965 TN Leens   Groningen                                   NLD Netherlands 53.3523 6.37    ;
9883 TB Oldehove    Groningen                                   NLD Netherlands 53.3108 6.3632
```

then

```
awk '!arr[$1]++' bigfile.txt
```

gives output

```
9417 TG Spier   Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.8178 6.4592  ;
9423 TA Hoogersmilde    Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.9098 6.3685  ;
9431 HK Westerbork  Drenthe                                 NLD Netherlands 52.8613 6.6029  ;
9883 TB Zuurdijk    Groningen                                   NLD Netherlands 53.3147 6.3558  ;
9965 TN Zuurdijk    Groningen                                   NLD Netherlands 53.3506 6.3691  ;
```

Explanation: `++` does return then increase by 1, `arr` is array (associative), if row with given 1st field was not yet encountered zero is assumed, `!` is negate, therefore for each line `arr[$1]` is starting at 0 number of occurence of given 1st field, as this is negated, only 0 cause default action of printing, so only 1st line for each unique first column value is printed.

Use `>` to save effect to file e.g.

```
awk '!arr[$1]++' bigfile.txt > bigfileunique.txt
```

and then just use it in your command that is

```
grep -f infile.txt bigfileunique.txt
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*